# Why there is no GzipContentEncoder in Jetty Client?

Tags: jetty, jetty-9, jetty-8, jetty-10

I can see org.eclipse.jetty.client.GZIPContentDecoder to decompress the compress response but unable to find any encoder to compress the request, is there any way to compress request using jetty Client library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty Client only has ContentDecoder for response decompression, not ContentEncoder for request compression.

I opened an enhancement issue for this feature ...

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/9619